# Change attribute from object using requestAnimationFrame in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I trying to update `human.x` using requestAnimationFrame and useState. I want to add elements called "humans" and use requestAnimationFrame to update the position to humans walk in "world" (using css properties). The method addHumans work but requestAnimationFrame update and empty my list.

**World.tsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Human from './Human'
import IHuman from './Human'

type IHuman = {
    id: number;
    x: number;
    y: number;
    color: string;
}

export default function World() {
    const [humans, setHumans] = useState<IHuman[]>([])

    const addHuman = () => {
        setHumans([...humans, {id: Math.random(), x: 0, y: 0, color: 'red'}])
    }

    const animate = () => {
        setHumans(humans?.map((human, i) => {
            return {...human, x: human.x + 1}
        }));
        // console.log(humans)
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }, []); // run once

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={addHuman}>new human</button>
            <main>
                {humans?.map(human => {
                    return <Human key = {human.id} x = {human.x} y = {human.y} color = {human.color} />
                })}
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Human.tsx**

```
export default function Human(props: any) {
    
    return (
        <div key={props.id} className="human" style={{ top: props.y + 'px', left: props.x + 'px', backgroundColor: props.color }}>{props.id}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a stale state. Update your code like this:

```
setHumans(humans => humans?.map((human, i) => {
  return {...human, x: human.x + 1}
}));
```

Comment: but this `humans` is from humans of useState or from the temporary variable of `setHumans`? I update using this code and not work. I tried `setHumans(hs => hs?.map....` and not work too...

Comment: @GuilhermeIazzetta Could you provide an example in Codesandbox or somewhere? This is mine: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-bogdan-67g95f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It worked! It was my mistake, I forgot to put the absolute position, that's why I wasn't moving the element. Thanks!